# Very generic argmax function in C++ wanted

Tags: c++, templates, generics, functional-programming

I'm a spoiled Python programmer who is used to calculating the [argmax](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Argmax) of a `collection` with respect to some `function` with

```
max(collection, key=function)
```

For example:

```
l = [1,43,10,17]
a = max(l, key=lambda x: -1 * abs(42 - x))
```

`a` then contains 43, the number closest to 42.

Is it possible to write a C++ function which takes any "iterable" and any function and returns the argmax like above? I guess this would involve template parameters, the `auto` keyword, and [range-based iteration](http://www.cprogramming.com/c++11/c++11-ranged-for-loop.html), but I was not able to piece it together.

Comment: What does `lambda x: -1 * abs(42 - x)` do?

Comment: @Nawaz It creates a function which maps the argument `x` to the absolute difference between 42 and `x`. Multiply by -1, because we want to minimize the difference.

Comment: @Nawaz I'm sure it is the equivalent of `[](int x){ return -1 * abs(42 - x); }`

Comment: Please note that your python code does not exactly match the definition of argmax you referenced as it returns a single value, not a set.

Comment: Good question, more about uniform iterators (a Good Thing) than about argmax. Fwiw, numpy `np.argmax( np.arange( 1000, dtype=float ))` takes 1.6 microsec on my stock iMac; a stupid-simple argmax in clang++ takes 1 microsec, i.e. 1 nanosec per loop.

Comment: your question is for finding the max, not argmax. (argmax : index of max value). For c++ std::vector argmax, see http://fundamentalthinking.blogspot.com/2016/04/min-max-argmin-argmax-of-stdvector-in-c.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since @leemes solutions are too many. All are correct, except that none attempts to *imitate* the Python version in your example, Here is my attempt to imitate that:

Convenient generic argmax-function just like Python version:

```
template<typename Container, typename Fn>
auto max(Container const & c, Fn && key) -> decltype(*std::begin(c))
{  
    if ( std::begin(c) == std::end(c) ) 
       throw std::invalid_argument("empty container is not allowed.");

    typedef decltype(*std::begin(c)) V;
    auto cmp = [&](V a, V b){ return key(a) < key(b); };
    return *std::max_element(std::begin(c), std::end(c), cmp);
}
```

And use it as:

```
std::vector<int> l = {1,43,10,17};
auto a = max(l, [](int x) { return -1 * std::abs(42-x); };

int l[] = {1,43,10,17}; //works with array also!
auto a = max(l, [](int x) { return -1 * std::abs(42-x); };
```

**Note:** Unlike the other solution, this `max()` returns the element itself, not the iterator to the element!

Also note this solution would work for user-defined container also:

```
namespace test
{
     template<size_t N>
     struct intcollection
     {
         int _data[N];
         int const * begin() const { return _data; }
         int const * end() const { return _data + N; }
     };
}

test::intcollection<4> c{{1,43,10,17}};
auto r = max(c, [](int x) { return -1 * std::abs(42-x); });
```

[See the live demo](http://stacked-crooked.com/view?id=8c5b827574be4247f3eb28e944462812).

Comment: What is the `->` operator here and `decltype`?

Comment: @cls: It is called trailing-return-type. It is C++11 feature. :-)

Comment: @cls: See this [Alternative function syntax](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B11#Alternative_function_syntax) which uses *trailing-return-type*.

Comment: @cls: And `decltype` deduces the *type* of the expression. So you can write `decltype(0) age = 40;` which is same as `int age = 40;`. In this case, it doesn't make much sense, but sometimes it is needed like in my solution.

Comment: If you are gonna use `std::begin`, do it with ADL!  So people can write custom containers.  :)  Second, note that your code executes undefined behavior on empty containers, which I doubt the python version did.

Comment: @Yakk Hugh, why is this? (UB for empty containers)

Comment: `std::max_element` returns `end` if passed an empty container, I think.

Comment: @Yakk: Fixed the UB. Also, `std::begin(c)` would call the custom container `.begin()` internally. So that is not a problem.

Comment: On the contrary @Nawaz: `namespace bar{struct foo{int data[10];};int*begin(foo&f){return &f.data[0];}int*end(foo&f){return begin(f)+10;}}int main(){bar::foo f;for(auto x:f){std::cout<<x<<"\n";}}` -- no `foo::begin`, yet adl-based `begin` lookup works, while `std::begin` does not.  Calling `std::begin(c)` directly is not quite the "right" thing to do, but it is close.  Replace call to `std::begin(c);` with `using std::begin; begin(c);` and you get ADL-based `begin` lookup.  It is a small problem, not a big one.

Comment: @Yakk: How would you write this `-> decltype(*std::begin(c))` to enable ADL, without writing `using std::begin` outside the function? Adding an ADL solution to this post would pollute it, which I don't want to do, *because* it is *not* required. I want to keep it simple and to the point which works for most containers, as long as it has member functions `begin()` and `end()`.

Comment: `namespace aux{using std::begin;template<typename C>auto adl_begin(C&&c)->decltype(begin(std::forward(c)));}`, then `->decltype(*aux::adl_begin(c))` is a technique that works.

Answer (score 8):

This is a two-step process. Define a function `key` which should get *mapped* to the elements, i.e. which is applied *before* the operation which finds the maximum. Wrap things together in a lambda expression *defining the comparison* for finding the maximum.

```
auto key = [](int x){
    return -abs(42 - x);
};

std::max_element(l.begin(), l.end(), [key](int a, int b){
    return key(a) < key(b);
});
```

Here, we have to capture `key` which was defined outside the second lambda function. (We could also have defined it inside). You can also put this in one single lambda function. When the 42 should be parameterized from outside the lambda, capture this as a variable:

```
int x = 42;
std::max_element(l.begin(), l.end(), [x](int a, int b){
    return -abs(x - a) < -abs(x - b);
});
```

Note that `std::max_element` returns an iterator. To access the value / a reference to it, prepend it with `*`:

```
int x = 42;
auto nearest = std::min_element(l.begin(), l.end(), [x](int a, int b){
    return abs(x - a) < abs(x - b);
});
std::cout << "Nearest to " << x << ": " << *nearest << std::endl;
```

You can nicely wrap this in a generic `find_nearest` function:

```
template<typename Iter>
Iter find_nearest(Iter begin, Iter end,
                  const typename std::iterator_traits<Iter>::value_type & value)
{
    typedef typename std::iterator_traits<Iter>::value_type T;
    return std::min_element(begin, end, [&value](const T& a, const T& b){
        return abs(value - a) < abs(value - b);
    });
}

auto a = find_nearest(l.begin(), l.end(), 42);
std::cout << *a << std::endl;
```

**Live demo** `find_nearest`: http://ideone.com/g7dMYI

---

A higher-order function similar to the `argmax` function in your question might look like this:

```
template<typename Iter, typename Function>
Iter argmax(Iter begin, Iter end, Function f)
{
    typedef typename std::iterator_traits<Iter>::value_type T;
    return std::min_element(begin, end, [&f](const T& a, const T& b){
        return f(a) < f(b);
    });
}
```

You can invoke this with the following code, having exactly the lambda function from your question:

```
auto a = argmax(l.begin(), l.end(), [](int x) { return -1 * abs(42 - x); });
std::cout << *a << std::endl;
```

**Live demo** `argmax`: http://ideone.com/HxLMap

---

The only remaining difference now is that this `argmax` function uses an *iterator-based* interface, which corresponds to the design of the C++ standard algorithms ([`<algorithm>`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/)). It's always a good idea to adapt your own coding style to the tools you're using.

If you want a *container-based* interface which returns the value directly, [Nawaz provided a nice solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14200316/592323) which requires the decltype-feature to correctly specify the return type. I decided to keep my version this way, so people can see the both alternative interface designs.

Comment: Nice answer, but the "find nearest" problem was just an example for the use of `max(collection, key=function)`, not the actual problem to be solved.

Comment: @cls I'll add a generic higher-order function solving the argmax problem.

Comment: @cls Here you go. The .begin() and .end() thing are typical for C++ algorithms, so I adopted the C++ style.

Comment: @cls: Also note that this solution returns the iterator to the element rather than element itself.

Comment: You should use `typedef std::iterator_traits<Iter>::value_type T`; to be correct, which is specialized for pointer iterators that don't have an inner-type `value_type`. Otherwise this answer's solution is the right way to go.

Comment: @GManNickG Ok I did't know this, thanks. No `typename` in this case?

Comment: @leemes: Yeah you need `typename`, my mistake. :)