# Using STL algorithms on unary functions

Tags: c++, std

So I often want to perform some STL algorithm on a range of elements and instead of a comparison function, I would like to pass a unary function f.

For example I would like to write something like this

```
std::max_element(begin(range), end(range), f);
```

to find the maximum element in the range after applying f.
My current workaround looks something like that:

```
std::max_element(begin(range), end(range, [&f](auto a, auto b){ return f(a) < f(b); });
```

At first glance, this may look like no problem. But f could be a lambda expression itself or in another way more complicate than just f.
I have two problem with that piece of code:
a) It is error prone because one could accidently write f(a) < f(a) (especially if more complicated and one used copy and past). This is the problem of code duplication
b) It does not express the intent very well. If I want to sort by a function, I do not want to deal with a comparison.

Unfortunately I have not found a good solution to this kind of problem in the standard library (or even boost), so I would like to ask you what your solution to this problem is. Is there any reason for the non-existence of this overload in the algorithms?

Comment: Boost's [transform iterator](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_75_0/libs/iterator/doc/html/iterator/specialized/transform.html) seems to be what you are looking for. In other words it's the iterators that you pass to max_element that should be adapted not the comparator.

Comment: With standard library this is not possible using existing functions. You need a combination of ````std::transform```` and ````max_element````. You could write a very simple templated wrapper function to achieve that. That is not complicated. 3 Lines of code . . .

Comment: Thanks for this idea! I still do not see how to avoid the problem though. The example given there also has the problem of code duplication.

Comment: Standard library functions cannot cover every possible requirement. There will always be times when you need something a bit different. You can always write your own function to meet your specific needs. You can still leverage the Standard Library to do the core part of this task.

Comment: That is definitely true. However at least for me, I have never used any other comparison fuction than comparing the value of the output of a unary function. Is there some way to overload *all* STL algorithms with a comparison function with one own function?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Very generic argmax function in C++ wanted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14199798/very-generic-argmax-function-in-c-wanted)

Comment: Unfortunatly, not really. It only solves the problem for a specific algorithm. Maximum is just an example, I would like this behaviour for every algorithm.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using c++ 20's ranges you can do:

```cpp
std::ranges::max_element(range | std::views::transform(f));
```

Comment: Why not pass a projection (3rd argument) to max_element?

Comment: I think it's the same thing in the end, but yes that would work aswell `max_element(range, {}, f);`

Comment: Personally I'd prefer the first version because the call to transform self-documents the code while the second version is not clear if you're not familiar with it

Comment: Unfortunately I currently only have access to c++17, but this will solve the problem nicely! I would prefer the second version since one can assume familiarity with the standard library.

Comment: You can have a look at eric niebler's ranges v3 library, it should work like this and is c++17 ( I think ) and you should be able to drop in and replace with stl once you have c++20 access

Answer (score 0):

One thing you can do is create your own generic comparator that accepts a unary function to perform a transform:

```
// Generic comparator
template<typename T, typename F>
struct transform_comparator_type
{
    transform_comparator_type(F f): f(f) {}
    bool operator()(T const& a, T const& b) const { return f(a) < f(b); }
    F f;
};

// Helper function to deduce the type of F
template<typename T, typename F>
auto transform_comparator(F f)
{
    return transform_comparator_type<T, F>(f);
}

int main()
{
    std::vector<int> v{1, 4, 3, 6, 0};

    auto e = std::max_element(std::begin(v), std::end(v),
        transform_comparator<int>([v](int i){ return 2 * i; }));

    // etc...
}
```

**Edited to add:**

The type can actually be deduced from the return type of the supplied transform function, so you don't need the helper function. You can do this instead:

```
template<typename F>
struct transform_comparator
{
    using T = decltype(F()({})); // deduce T from return type of F
    transform_comparator(F f): f(f) {}
    bool operator()(T const& a, T const& b) const { return f(a) < f(b); }
    F f;
};
```

Comment: This looks like a good solution for c++17 and it also solves an even more general problem. I have also looked for something like that in the STL or boost, but have not found it, which is IMO quite weird because it is a common problem (or is it not?).

Comment: I think most people would just write the comparator as a lambda where they need it.